# Flutter , Debug Error without Explanation

Tags: flutter, dart

when debugging  , I am facing an issue  ,
the debug error is missing the explanation and details.
here is the debug console output :

[image]

any idea what is the problem here :
attached Flutter Doctor :

```
## Flutter Doctor ##

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-EG)
    • Flutter version 1.22.1 at /Users/XXXXX/flutter
    • Framework revision f30b7f4db9 (7 days ago), 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 75bef9f6c8
    • Dart version 2.10.1

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/XXXXXX/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.6, Build version 11E708
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 50.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 191.6183.88

[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
   • iPhone 11 Pro Max (mobile) • AECA9290-F1AE-45BF-8D0C-6D6A7F6B648D • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-6 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I guess you have `ListView` ?

Comment: can you share your code?